# Creating dependencies between projects

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have an app which is deployed as two separate web projects - w1 & w2. A parent project P contains the w1 & w2. Code has been added to w1 which uses code on w2 so I need to add w2 to classpath of w1 in order to use this code. Each web project should be self contained so is creating this dependency a bad practice?

Also, this is Maven project so, in order for the .war to build, w2 will need to be created as a dependency. I think this is just opening a lot of issues with dependency management between the projects.

I think a separate jar project should be created which just contains the code to be shared and then add this as a dependency.

Comment: _Each web project should be self contained_ which mean do everything on your own. I am afraid its not the way

Comment: Check maven overlays, it could help to merge shared web resources. But this is kinda hack, really a web app should be self-contained.

Comment: It would not work that way (using direct dependencies from w1 to w2). War dependencies are automatically applied as overlays (w1 would include everything from w2 as well). However, this is applied in the package phase. So during compile, your code from w2 would not be visible to the compiler, i.e. w1 would not even compile. Please use a separate jar as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would consider this to be bad practice.  In a container that properly isolates the classloaders of the wars at runtime, you would see errors in your w1 project.  If you are creating two self-contained wars and want to reuse a piece of code / functionality, I would suggest creating a 3rd project that builds to a jar containing that functionality.  Your two web projects can then include that library as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have code components in w1 which is needed in w2 and vice versa you should extract those component into a separate "common" project, which both w1 & w2 depend on. Particularily since you have other dependencies as well (Spring, etc.)